# How to access page variable inside action hook

Tags: filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I have an action hook which simply displays a contact form for signup:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_product_signup', 10, 2);
function add_product_signup() {
    do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="20709" title="Product Sale Notification Signup"]');
}
```

This works ok BUT... I want to only show the form if the product is NOT on sale.

How can I access the 'on_sale' variable to test for true/false to then show/hide this contact form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is method on product class that is called `is_on_sale()` which actually determines if the product is on sale or not. You can access it from `global $product` variable. And must `echo` the `do_shortcode`. So the whole code will be like-

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_product_signup', 10, 2);
function add_product_signup() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="20709" title="Product Sale Notification Signup"]');
    }
}
```

> **The above code is tested. I tested it personally and it worked pretty well.**

Comment: Oh, Of course.  I forgot the global $product... I was getting an error on the if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {  and figured I couldn't access it. Thanks . Worked perfectly